# Maui How to detect when user arrives end of ScrollView. (infinite scrolling)

Tags: xaml, scrollview, maui, infinite-scroll

I have a page using a ScrollView.
In this page i show a list.
This list I get from a rest-interface.
The list could be very long, so I'm loading only a amount of items from the rest interface, lets say 30 items.
When the user is scrolling down and comes to the end of the list and ScrollView I would like to load the next 30 items from the rest interface and add them to the view.

**How can I detect when the user arrives the lower end of a Maui ScrollView?**

Comment: ScrollView has a ScrollY, and a Scrolled event. Add an event handler, and compare ScrollY to a previously saved value, plus some offset (use the scrollview height, minus a small amount). Whenever you've scrolled "enough", load more, and remember this new "previous offset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the end of the list item of [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview) when the user arrives the lower end of it, you can use the code below to achieve it:

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollView  Scrolled="OnScrollViewScrolled"> 
     <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{x:Static local:NamedColor.All}">
           <!--Omitted for breviety-->
      </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void OnScrollViewScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e) 
{

      if (!(sender is ScrollView scrollView)) return;

      var scrollSpace =  scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;

      if (scrollSpace > e.ScrollY) return;
      

      //load more items when coming to the end of the list of ScrollView 
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load more items");
}
```

Comment: If the `ScrollView` is already positioned at the end of the `StackLayout`, the event `OnScrollViewScrolled` is not raised, how to do in that case please ?